# Convert SQL Binary to byte array

Tags: c#

Given some data stored in a SQL binary field:

```
0x83C8BB02E96F2383870CC1619B6EC...
```

I'd like to convert it into a byte array, but it doesn't seem like I can just cast this directly into a byte like so:

```
byte[] someBytes = (byte) 0x83C8BB02E96F2383870CC1619B6EC...;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Uh? Querying the DB for a binary field will return a byte array.

Comment: What do you have right now? Literal text? A string?

Comment: Say I'm in Query Analyzer, and I SELECT from a binary field, the result grid has the value from above (I truncated the example because it's over 300 characters long).

Comment: Why is there binary data in the database?

Comment: Because that's how I inherited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data stored in the SQL field is in binary.  The '0x83..' string you quoted is just a hexadecimal representation of that binary data.

If you just want to copy/paste the hexadecimal data into your C# code (as you seem to have written), then you'll need to convert it from hexadecimal to binary.  .NET provides a (rather obscure) class for this sort of thing:

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary

public byte[] ToBytes(string hex)
{
    var shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse(hex);
    return shb.Value;
}

public void TestConvert()
{
    byte[] someBytes = ToBytes("83C8BB02E96F2383870CC1619B6EC");
}
```

If your binary data is coming from your database in a different form than a copy/pasted string, you'll need to provide more information about your setup.

Comment: Removing the `0x` from the string is a subtle but important difference between the data that would be copied and the example here. Without doing that you will get `xsd:hexBinary` errors

Comment: I'm getting `xsd:hexBinary invalid` errors even after removing the `0x`. Edit: removing one character from the end (to make the length even, I suppose) fixed it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in .NET Core? I can't find an analogous library

Answer (score 4):

Your casting is wrong.

```
byte[] someBytes = (byte[]) 0x83C8BB02E96F2383870CC1619B6EC...;
```

I had the same problem and I stumbled across this question. After further research I tried casting like the above and it worked.

Comment: I'm getting error "Integral constant is too large".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36621222/4009972):

Remove the `0x` from the beginning of your data and create a string:

```
var stringHex = "83C8BB02E96F2383870CC1619B6EC...";
```

Then convert to byte[] with this method:

```
byte[] myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, stringHex.Length / 2)
                           .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(stringHex.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16))
                           .ToArray();
```

I had to use this method because my data was too long, so I was getting errors about Int32 and Int64 overflow.