# How do I convert a byte array represented as a string into a byte array?

Tags: c#, .net

In SQL Server, a varbinary(max) looks like '0xFE12CE34AB27' when looking at query results in a grid result within Management Studio. How can I copy a value looking like that and convert it back into a byte array via C#?

Comment: So just to clarify, you're *copying the string value* (e.g. via the clipboard) - this isn't about fetching from the database in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916049/convert-sql-binary-to-byte-array

Comment: If you retrieve the value from the database using C# it wont be in a string representation. Also Management Studio might not be showing the complete binary file but rather the first part of it.

Comment: Jon, you're correct, I'm just trying to copy and paste the value into LinqPad to decode it as I'm just trying to troubleshoot something quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The `'0xFE12CE34AB27'` string you see is an artifact of the Mgmt Studio.

Your data already is a byte array, don't do anything.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the artifact into linqpad as a string.

Comment: Then say 'via Clipboard', not 'via C#'. Seems like you're using the wrong tool(s) here.

Comment: @JamesAlexander You are not guaranteed to get the complete binary file if you do it like that. Mgmt Studio cuts the data.