# Decompress SQL Server compressed varbinary Array in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, compression, gzip

I have a table in SQL Server with a `varbinary(MAX)` column which is filled with SQL `Compress` method of JSON string with utf8 characters for example `{"id": 12, title: "فروش"}` in the sql I use `CAST(DECOMPRESS(data) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` and result is ok.

In the c# I use this code for decompressing the data column:

```
public static string Unzip(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            CopyTo(gs, mso);
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
    }
}
```

But the result is an invalid string:

[image]

Comment: It's [`DeflateStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36621222/11683).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your string is in the format "Unicode" but you are trying to use the encoding type UTF8?

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the encoding and every things got right.

Comment: You are quite welcome, I just realized how much of a nerd I am, I recognized the unicode format...

ugh. I need to re-evaluate my life :D

Comment: @mortenBork relax, we all have our own unique nerd super powers. This is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you have the default Collations enabled in SQL, `NVARCHAR` will be returned as Unicode while `VARCHAR` will be returned as UTF-8.  You could also use [SQL Output Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#output-collation) to force an encoding:

`SELECT CAST('abc' AS varchar(5)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`

Answer (score -1):

In your `SELECT` you should use `DECOMPRESS`

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/decompress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I use entity frame work for fetching data is there method in ef which does the same job?

Comment: Nope, you can make a view which takes the result already decompressed and use it with EF

Comment: Using `DECOMPRESS` would defeat the purpose of returning compressed data from SQL..  This doesn't answer the OP's question as they are trying to read a compressed stream, not decompress the stream and then read it.